# Ocaml manipulating lists

Tags: list, ocaml

real basic question here: I'm new to Ocaml and I'm having issues trying to manipulate lists. I've read http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/List.html, and I'm unfortunately still confused....I'm new to functional programming.

If I have, say, the following function:

```
  let stoverfl list1 list2 list3 =
      match list1 with
      |[]->None
      |h::list1 -> (*what I want to do goes in here*)
```

I want to take a look at the first elements of list2 and list3, compare them, and if they're equal, add the first element of list3 to list2, else don't modify the lists.  I don't really care about error checking now (i.e. checking to see if the list has at least one element, etc.).

My attempt:

```
 h::list1 -> let cmp1 = hd list2 (*this should return the first elemnt of list2??*)
             let cmp2 = hd list3
             if(cmp1=cmp2) then
                let updlist2 = concat list2 hd list3
                let updlist3 = hd list3
                (*pass updlist2 and updlist3 instead of list2 and list3 to next function*)
             else
                (*do nothing; pass list2 and list3 as normal*)
```

I feel like I'm doing it all wrong...any advice would be appreciated!
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say you want to add the first element of `list3` to `list2`. When a functional programmer says something like this what it means is that they want to construct a new list as described. You can't actually modify `list2`--lists are immutable and names are permanently bound to a single value. In fact, it seems like you want to construct *two* new lists. One of them has the first element of `list2` at the front of `list3`. The other one is the remainder of `list2` (all but the first element).

Assuming this is what you mean, and assuming you're not worried whether the lists are empty, then here's one way to get these values:

```
let updlist2 = List.tl list2 in
let updlist3 = (List.hd list2) :: list3
```

It's actually pretty close to what you wrote.

However, I wonder what you're going to do with these values next. If you want to pass them along to another function, it would be more normal to have the `let`s *outside* the `if`. As an example, here's some code that calls a function `g` with either a list, or the tail of the list, depending on the first element of the list:

```
let arg_for_g =
    match the_list with
    | [] -> []  (* No tail of the list *)
    | head :: tail -> if head = 3 then tail else the_list
in
    g arg_for_g
```

If you put the `let`s inside the `if`, you'll need to code two different calls to your next function. That could be fine, it depends on exactly what you're going to do with your values.

(As a side note, you should worry about whether the lists are empty! If you use a `match` statement you can detect that case pretty easily.)